# Network proxy blocks socket.io

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, proxy

I'm using `nodejs`, `socket.io` and apache on the same server. Apache redirect requests from port 80 to 443 and after that it makes with the `SSLProxyEngine` a indirect redirect to my SSL-NodeJS server on port 3000 - Working fine,

**The problem:**

In some areas, only the ports 80 and 443 are allowed, not port 3000.

When I change:

```
io.connect('https://domain.com:3000', { path: '/socket.io' });
```

to this:

```
io.connect('https://domain.com', { path: '/socket.io' });
io.connect('https://domain.com:443', { path: '/socket.io' });
// whatever ...
```

the server is not reachable (`net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

I tried to put the port to an public one like FTP (21) but the Browser said that this is not allowed to use this port.

Do you have any ideas?

Here are some files:

Apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com

    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    ProxyPass / https://domain.com:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / https://domain.com:3000/
    // localhost not working 

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    ...
    SSLCertificateFile       ...
    SSLCertificateChainFile  ...

</VirtualHost>
```

(I replaced my domain with domain.com)

Comment: Did you find a solutio for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
working very well.

HTTP => com.domain.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

HTTPS (using LetsEncrypt) => com.domain-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

        <Location />
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
        </Location>

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

client.js

```
var url = window.location.href;
var domain = url.split("/")[0] + "//" + url.split("/")[2];

var socket = io.connect(domain, { path: '/socket.io' });

socket.on('hello', function(callback) {
    callback(); // confirm receiving "hello"
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log('HTTP-Server started on port ' +     port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('connection: ' + socket.id);

    socket.emit('hello', function(res) {
        console.log('Client received "hello"');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(exception) {
        console.log('disconnect: ' + socket.id);
    });

});
```

Tipp: If you have not installed a firewall, do it and block port 3000 (or the port you are using).